# What functionality AI expert system what has functionality of ´businessmen´ would have?

Tags: econometrics, mathematical-economics, markets

Economy experts!
If you imagine a machine learning / expert system project, or something similar, what goal is to create a system what would perform the same task as a ´businessmen´ in market economy, means for example an owner of some big company? As input this system would have economy situation (any possible data about it), and as output - the solution, what exactly data would you say would be  given as an input, and what exactly economy tasks (parts of the term ´businessmen functionality´) must this system perform?